# How can I make the following menu using CSS?

Tags: css, menu, background

I have this menu:
[image]

How can I make active white background behind text (ul,li)?

How can I make the background white text on mouse-over? (Contact,Recommended Downloads)

This is image for background:

[image]

Comment: Btw, we have CSS gradients now, so you don't need those images.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas which is all well and good if you don't care about backwards compatibility...

Comment: @Shmiddty It's just appearance. IE<10 gets a solid color, modern browsers get a gradient. There's nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: Can you please give an example of this solution? Thank you.

Comment: @Shmiddty There is always http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I need a solution with this picture. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menuButton:hover
{
background:white;
}
```

This, hover, should change the color of background when hovering over the div